# Heroku Deplyoment fails because of Error: Cannot find module 'next-themes'

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js

I'm deploying a NextJS application to Heroku.
The whole build process runs smoothly without any errors, yet the deployed page throws a „Internal Server Error"

Heroku Logs are show this error:

```
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061154+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'next-themes'
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061175+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061176+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/.next/server/pages/_app.js
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061176+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061177+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061177+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061178+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061178+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061178+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061179+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061180+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:183:28)
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061181+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061181+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061181+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061182+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.1162 (/app/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1419:18)
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061182+00:00 app[web.1]: at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061182+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.8811 (/app/.next/server/pages/_app.js:24:29)
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061183+00:00 app[web.1]: at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061183+00:00 app[web.1]: at __webpack_exec__ (/app/.next/server/pages/_app.js:1555:39) {
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061184+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061184+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061184+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/.next/server/pages/_app.js',
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061185+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061185+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js',
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061185+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js',
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061185+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js',
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061186+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js',
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061186+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061186+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2022-04-06T11:01:00.061186+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Which is odd since „next-themes" is part of the package.json and does not throw any errors in build or local production.

Package.Json looks like this:
[image]

Comment: "Which is odd since „next-themes" is part of the package.json"—please show us that file.

Comment: Added as an edit.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: But the issue is that you have declared this as a _dev_ dependency. I'll find a duplicate for you.